# Codeigniter guide Create News Item data not inserting

Tags: php, codeigniter, phpmyadmin, routes

I am following https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/tutorial/create_news_items.html from CI User guide .

Now the problem is: when i proceed with "index.php/news/create", data not inserting into the database and not successfully redirecting to success.php

#### *config/routes.php*

```
    $route['default_controller'] = 'frontpage';
    $route['404_override'] = '';


    $route['(:any)'] = 'templates/view/$1';
    $route['(:any)'] = 'include/view/$1';


    $route['news/(:any)'] = 'news/$1';
    $route['news'] = 'news';
    $route['(:any)'] = 'pages/view/$1';

    $route['news/create'] = 'news/create';
    $route['news/(:any)'] = 'news/view/$1';
```

and the **application/controller/news.php**

```
<?php
class News extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('news_model');
    }

public function create()
{
    $this->load->helper('form');
    $this->load->library('form_validation');

    $data['title'] = 'Create a news item';

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('title', 'Title', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('text', 'text', 'required');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE)
    {
        $this->load->view('include/header', $data);
        $this->load->view('news/create');
        $this->load->view('include/footer');

    }
    else
    {
        $this->news_model->set_news();
        $this->load->view('news/success');
    }
}
```

**models/news_model.php**

```
<?php
class News_model extends CI_Model {

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->load->database();
    }
      

public function set_news()
{
    $this->load->helper('url');

    $slug = url_title($this->input->post('title'), 'dash', TRUE);

    $data = array(
        'title' => $this->input->post('title'),
        'slug' => $slug,
        'text' => $this->input->post('text')
    );

    return $this->db->insert('news', $data);
}
        
}
```

and the create.php and success.php files are same as user guide . can someone point what is the fault ,

Edited :

create.php

```
<h2>Create a news item</h2>

<?php echo validation_errors(); ?>

<?php echo form_open('index.php/news/success') ?>

    <label for="title">Title</label>
    <input type="input" name="title" /><br />

    <label for="text">Text</label>
    <textarea name="text"></textarea><br />

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Create news item" />

</form>
```

Very much thanks in advance ! :)

Comment: are there any mysql error displaying or is it really passing inside the model?

Comment: hi @reignsly : when i clicked the "Create News Item Button" it redirect to the "localhost/news/create" it should be "localhost/index.php/news/success" as i think right ?

Comment: in you form, it says that it will post to `localhost/news/create`, from here it will save that data using the model. Then when successfull it will redirect to `news/success`. But if the data saving will not be successfull it will stay at the /new/create. I suggest you should check the saving and the validation form if it returns true. :)

Comment: [Sample Debug](http://pastebin.com/JidQfNZL) <- Can you try this code and tell me what will be the output?

Comment: hi @reignsly it shows "string(0) "" Failed" when i run "/index.php/news/create" path

Comment: Can you run again [this](http://pastebin.com/J1vyXNZp) please.

The problem is the validation run returns false.

Comment: it shows "array(0) { } Failed" now @reignsly .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your input type like this:

```
 <input type="text" name="title" /><br />
```

Comment: Hi didn't figure out the problem , but i proceeded with the fresh installment again , and it works :)

Comment: Good for you. Happy Coding :)